# After installing xampp in ubuntu, phpMyAdmin is asking for username and password:

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I had installed xampp in ubuntu. phpMyAdmin is now asking for authentication and asking for username and password. How do i solve this problem.

Comment: Press enter , it will set default username 'root' and password will empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try default username is "root" & Password is empty " "

Comment: while installing  xampp did you set any username password? if you forget that look at this -- https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1032

Comment: i did not get any username or password while installing.

Comment: Ok try to set new user name & password follow this link - https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1032

Comment: what password should i enter while loging in as root

Comment: the default password is empty (" "), if you want to set the password use your own password like "123". Note:  chk " php.ini "  file.

Comment: Open browser and type " http://localhost/phpmyadmin " if this page shows login dialog then check the php.ini file.... then you need to change authentication method

Comment: What version of xampp u have? where u downloaded from? and tell ur OS Name, version 32bit/64bit

Comment: XAMPP 1.8.3-2 , installed from http://ubuntuportal.com/2013/12/how-to-install-xampp-1-8-3-for-linux-in-ubuntu-desktop.html

Comment: Operating system: Ubuntu, 32-bit

Comment: after installed XAMPP, change phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file settings as following. 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Answer (score 0):

Go to config.inc.php file using terminal by typing the following:

```
sudo gedit /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

The file will open in gedit.

Now open the file and edit

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

and keep the 
`username: root`
`password: ''`

Also make sure that the lines with username and password are not commented:

```
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Make sure that // is removed from the above lines.